# How to prevent character from jumping multiple times

Tags: unity, c#

I just started learning Unity yesterday, Ive asked in many forums/servers this question but no one gave me a solution for my problem (in the title) so here's my code:

```
public class scr : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 1f;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    public float jumpforce = 1f;
    private bool isGrounded;
    public float disToGround = 0.5f;

    //Vai obter o rigid body do character
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    //Movimentaçao do character 
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0f , moveVertical);

        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);

        if (isGrounded == false && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpforce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to change the value of `isGrounded`. Did you forget to add some code to the question? Also, keep in mind that this site uses English, so when posting code, you might want to translate the comments in English so that other users give you better help (they'll understand more what you're trying to achieve).

Comment: Adding to the suggestion by Alexander, I would say that you’re also doing AddForce inside if, where the trigger condition is `isGrounded == false`. That means, if the player is in the air, and the Space key is pressed, a secondary jump will occur

Comment: We have lots of existing Q&A [about preventing/controlling double jumping in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=unity+double+jump), and [how to perform ground checks](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=unity+ground+check). Please be sure to read these existing resources thoroughly and make your best effort to implement one of these already-vetted solutions. If you run into a specific problem making one of these solutions work, please edit your question to show what you tried and where it's going wrong, and we can re-open it for fresh answers.